# Is the relation $\{ (a,b) \in\Bbb Z^2 : |a-b| \le 10 \}$ an equivalence relation or not ??

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Is the relation ↖ an equivalence relation or not ??

I know we are supposed to prove that it is reflexive , transitive and symmetric . I found that it is an equivalence relation but i am not sure , so can you please take a look and tell me if it is correct or not ??

Comment: Are you sure that it’s transitive? What if $a=0,b=10$, and $c=20$?

Comment: Yes , you are right . It is not transitive in this case . Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It seems your question/comment was "spot on." Perhaps you'd like to post an answer to the question?

Comment: @amWhy: Done! $~$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Are you sure that it’s transitive? What if $a=0,b=10$, and $c=20$?

Comment: Good enough for +1!